# What is the source of "Shami and Egyptian fight each other... and a man... with small black banners... will hand over the rule to the Mahdi"?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I am seeing the following hadith being quoted at many places (e.g. [ShiaChat](http://www.shiachat.com/forum/topic/234997619-mahdi-willl-be-from-khurasan-afghanistan/?page=2), [TurnToIslam](http://turntoislam.com/community/threads/the-mehdi-the-reviver-of-islam.5524/)) but I cant find the reference book for this:

> "When a man rules over ash-Sham, and another over Egypt, and the Shami and Egyptian fight each other,
>   and the people of ash-Sham take some of the tribes of Egypt captive, and a man comes forward from the
>   east with small black banners towards the ruler of ash-Sham, then it is he who will hand over the rule to the [Mahdi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahdi)."

Comment: can you add where have seen this hadith

Comment: google the hadith you will find it is quoted in many blogs on Mahdi topic

Comment: To my knowledge there is no authentic Hadith in which name Mahdi is mentioned

Answer (score -4):

Naim bin Hammad narrated it from Kab bin Alqamah in *Kitab al-Fitan*.  It is not the words of the Prophet Mohamed.

General rule:  Any *hadith* mentioning "mahdi" is weak.

Comment: can you substantiate " Any hadith mentioning "mahdi" is weak." with proof

Comment: how can you say mahdi(a.s.) as such he is reality and you all will know the truth during the day of judjement

Comment: @Sayyid thats an interesting claim. Please share your research as  a Q\A here.

Comment: Your answer is really low quality.

Comment: Are you really suggesting that [all these hadiths](http://www.al-islam.org/shiite-encyclopedia-ahlul-bayt-dilp-team/sunni-documentation-imam-al-mahdi) are weak? Have you examined all of them individually?

Comment: Every single one is either weak or proven to be a lie.  I have examined them myself but hadith scholars have done some of the research already.  And isn't it odd that al-Bukhari and Muslim didn't even bother putting them in their books?  If it was such an important topic they would've at least mentioned something in similar form.  Do your own research and bring the strongest isnad you can find.  And I'll show you why it's weak.  There's a suspicion that Mahdi hadiths were fabricated to justify certain rulers and their dhulm.

Comment: @MohammadHossein if you can do a better job pls don't hesitate to reply

Comment: @Sayyid, but what is your criterion to determine which hadith is weak or strong?